# What is memory interlock?

Tags: linux, synchronization, operating-system, hardware

Recently I came across the term "Memory interlocked test and set instruction?". I am not able to understand the term.. Can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a basic atomic instruction in other to do many stuff in parallel programming. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set)

Answer (score 1):

> At the lowest level of the process management, the hardware must provide a memory interlocked test-and-set instruction. The test-and-set instruction must allow two operations to be done on a main-memory location—the reading of the existing value followed by the writing of a new value—without any other processor being able to read or write that memory loca- tion between the two memory operations. Some architectures support more com- plex versions of the test-and-set instruction.

Take from [Introduction to Process Management](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0201702452/samplechapter/mckusick_ch04.pdf).